Interfacing ADC12138 with Digital Discovery using SPI
I am trying to interface ADC12138  ADC over SPI channel to Digital Discovery to read the single ended analog voltage in the rang of 0-4V on channel 2.

As described in datasheet section 1.0 
Snapshot from TI's ADC12138 datasheet .
I started with Autocal command , Two read status commands and then channel selection command to expect the data on DO pin of ADC but not able to see the correct data. Here is the code lines i am executing to read the channel 2 using Digital Discovery .
      Protocol.SPI.Start()
      Protocol.SPI.ReadWrite(8,[0x08])// Autocal command 
      Protocol.SPI.ReadWrite(8,[0x0D])// 12 bit output with no sign 
      Protocol.SPI.ReadWrite(8,[0x09])//auto zero command
      wait(1)
      Protocol.SPI.ReadWrite(12,[0x0C])// Read status multiple times
      Protocol.SPI.ReadWrite(12,[0x0C])
      Protocol.SPI.ReadWrite(12,[0x0C])
      Protocol.SPI.ReadWrite(12,[0x0C])
      Protocol.SPI.ReadWrite(12,[0x0C])
      Protocol.SPI.ReadWrite(12,[0x0C])
      wait(1)
      while(1)
     {
      Protocol.SPI.ReadWrite(12,[0x90])// select channel 2 , single ended 
      Protocol.SPI.ReadWrite(12,[0x90])// select again channel 2 
      wait(1)
      var c=Protocol.SPI.Read(12,[1])// Reading 1 word of 12 bits 
      print(c[1])
      print(c[0])
      var Channel = (c/4096)*5
      print("Voltage  :" , Channel )
      Protocol.SPI.Stop()
      } 

Is there anything missing from code's perspective here ?
